What does UNKNOWN indicates in Micronaut liveness endpoint?
I enabled health endpoint in micronaut application. when I visit /health/liveness, status is coming as UNKNOWN. Documentation shows that UNKNOWN` also return status code 200 but doesn't give any info on what it is.

Why UNKNOWN` is returning 200?
According to micronaut-liveness-always-unknown I have create  a bean with @Liveness to get liveness endpoint enabled. I don't understand why we have to do that, in spring actuator both liveness and readiness are enabled by default


checked documentation

